# No permission to access SQL server perfmon counters

Tags: windows, sql-server, security, perfmon, performance-counters

My DBA team doesn't have access to SQL server 2005 standard performance counters.

What is the required permission that they should be granted? I found some registry entries, but they already have permissions there. they're not OS administrators.

Comment: Does your DBA team need to view output from existing performance counters, or do they need to add / remove performance counters? On which version of Windows is the SQL Server 2005 running?

Comment: They need to view output of existing performance counters. I have this situation on Standard and Enterprise edition on 3 different machines. Lots of other machines (installed from the same media) don't have that problem.

Answer (score 1):

Are you speaking of the `sys.dm_os_performance_counters` [DMV](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187743.aspx) ?
You need to grant the SQL Server login the VIEW SERVER STATE permission.

```
GRANT VIEW SERVER STATE to [performance_user]
```

This will also give the user account access to all other DMV's, & may not be granular enough.  Simply granting SELECT permission on the view doesn't work!!

If you want to do this outside of SQL Server & use the Performance Monitor mmc, then look at this [MSKB article.](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/300702)  You will need to modify some file level permissions & registry level permissions on the server:

> If the systemroot is on an NTFS
>   partition, you must have at least Read
>   access to the following two files:
>
> - `%SystemRoot%\System32\Perfc009.dat`
> - `%SystemRoot%\System32\Perfh009.dat`
>
> You must have at least Read access to
>   the following registry keys on the
>   remote computer:
>
> - `HKEYLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurePipeServers\winreg`
> - `HKEYLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Perflib`
>
> You must have Full access to the
>   following registry key on the remote
>   computer:
>
> - `HKEYLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\servicename\performance`

Comment: I meant the performance monitor. I checked the permissions and those guys already have read access in that points.

Answer (score 0):

Is the remote registry service running on the affected machines? Also, add the domain user accounts for the DBA's (or better yet, create a domain group for the DBA's) and add the domain users or group to the local Performance Monitor Users group.